# Rails: No route matches [POST] "/specials/1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

This is the error I'm getting:

```
No route matches [POST] "/specials/1"
```

I understand that it's not able to produce the post route, or it isn't available.

Here's my view/form code:

```
  <%= form_for(:special, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @special.id}) do |f| %>

    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-condensed table-hover" summary="Special form fields">
      <tr>
        <th>Order</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field :order, class: "form-control" %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Fine Print</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field :fine_print, class: "form-control" %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Active</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field :active, class: "form-control" %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Update Special") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

Heres's my controller code:

class SpecialsController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    @specials = Special.sorted
  end

  def show
    @special = Special.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @special = Special.new
  end

  def create
    #Instantiation of object using form parameters
    @special = Special.new(special_params)
    #Save the object
    if @special.save
      #If success, redirect to index action
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      # Redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @special = Special.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    #Find an existing object using form parameters
    @special = Special.find(params[:id])
    #Update the object
    if @special.update_attributes(special_params)
      #If succeeds, redirect to index action
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @special.id)
    else
      # If update fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
  end

private
  def special_params
    params.require(:special).permit(:name, :description, :fine_print, :active, :order)
  end

end
```

I noticed that there is an update path:

```
PATCH   /specials/:id(.:format) specials#update
```

I can't figure out why the post route isn't being applied. It's looking for the right @special instance, but it doesn't seem to have the route available. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when updating a record, we do a patch request to the route. Your form should look like this:

```
<%= form_for(@special) do |f| %>
```

Rails will determine the correct route is `PATCH   /specials/:id` based on the fact that `@special` has been persisted to the database.

If you decide to use this same form as a partial in your `new` view, just make sure to add this to your controller:

```
def new
  @special = Special.new
end
```

That way whether you are on the `new` route or the `edit` route, there will always be a `@special` object for `form_for` to infer whether to POST to `/specials` or PATCH `/specials/:id`

Comment: That didn't work. It threw a different error: undefined local variable or method `subject_params' for #<SpecialsController:0x0000000c174178>

Comment: Either `subject_params` should be `special_params` or you did not define a `subject_params` method for your `SpecialsController`. Can you update your answer with the full code from your `SpecialsController`?

Comment: I added the code. I changed the special_params, but it didn't work out.

Comment: What's the error message now? Did you change the `form_for` as well?

Comment: Could there be a mix up between the specials in the pages controller and the specials controller?

Comment: It's the same one.

Comment: Can you post your routes file and the current error message?

Comment: I forgot to try the form_for

Comment: Is this a rails 5 thing?

Comment: What if I want to delete the special?

Comment: For more information take a look at Rails Tutorial [Ch 10: Updating and Deleting Users](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-deleting_users) and [Ch 13: User Microposts](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-destroying_microposts)